# htaccess https redirect from www to non-www

Tags: htaccess, wp-redirect, https

I have added `.htaccess` `https` redirect from `www` to `non-www` with:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|off
    RewriteCond http%1://%{HTTP_HOST} ^(https?://)(www\.)?(.+)$
    RewriteRule ^ %1%3%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>`
```

When I visit my domain, the following redirects happen without any problem:

```
http://www.example.com     → http://example.com
http://www.example.com/abc → http://example.com/abc
```

But when I visit my domain as `https://www.example.com` or `https://www.example.com/abs`, my domain does not redirect and shows the error code: `SSL_ERROR_INTERNAL_ERROR_ALERT` (in Firefox) or `ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR` (in Chrome)

I have used WordPress and the plugin Really Simple SSL.

Any idea on how to fix my error?

Comment: Question: 1. Did you install any SSL certificate? 2. Do you want all your `http` requests to go to `https`?

Comment: 1- i have install SSL certificate Comodo. current website visitors as [https://example.com](https://example.com)
2 - i want reditect: whent visitors [https://www.example.com](https://www.example.com) reditect to [https://example.com](https://example.com)

Thanks

Comment: I've given an answer with mod_rewrite. However, if the problem persists, then the issue is somewhere else. In that case I'll need more info. for example do you use any service like Cloudflare? What's your SSL config CODE? etc.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Before I give you the CODE, let me explain a few points:

**Point 1:**

It's better if you only allow `https` links. Mixing `http` & `https` for the same content ***[breaks the security](https://medium.com/google-developer-experts/the-importance-of-using-https-all-the-way-9c65c0224e86)*** added by `https`. With `http`, you can never be sure that your visitors are shown the same page you are providing from your server.

**Point 2:**

Search engines consider `http` & `https` sites to be different sites, even when the domain is the same. So if not set up properly, you may get duplicate penalty. So it's recommended to go `https` all the way for better ***SEO*** as well.

**Point 3:**

Even with proper `.htaccess` CODE, you may get the same error if SSL is not set up properly. So after you change the `.htaccess` CODE, it's better to test your SSL setup against standards. You may use tool such as [this](https://www.sslchecker.com/sslchecker).

## Recommended CODE:

Based on the points above, following is the CODE you may use:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}        =off   [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$          "https://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]

    # remaining htaccess mod_rewrite CODE for WordPress
</IfModule>
```

This will do the following example redirects:

```
http://www.example.com/     → https://example.com/
http://www.example.com/abc  → https://example.com/abc
https://www.example.com/    → https://example.com/
https://www.example.com/abc → https://example.com/abc

# Additionally, even if your site is reachable by IP or
# some other domains or subdomains, this CODE will fix that too
http://Your_Server_IP/abc          → https://example.com/abc
http://sub-dmoani.example.com/abc  → https://example.com/abc
http://www.other-domain.com/abc    → https://example.com/abc
```

## Not Recommended CODE:

If for some reason, you don't want to follow the above recommendation & still want to allow both `http` and `https`, you may use the following CODE (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20419821/854549)):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # set protocol variable
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =on
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:https]
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [env=proto:http]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$       "%{ENV:proto}://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]

    # remaining htaccess mod_rewrite CODE for WordPress
</IfModule>
```

This will do the following example redirects:

```
http://www.example.com/     → http://example.com/
http://www.example.com/abc  → http://example.com/abc

https://www.example.com/    → https://example.com/
https://www.example.com/abc → https://example.com/abc
```

Comment: Thx. For me, adding this to .htaccess causes no change. I'm trying to redirect https to http (we have no ssl for now) and simultaniously redirect www to non-www. Either w/ htaccess or via php in functions.php. Can you take a look at my question and see if you can halp?https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286464/php-redirect-https-to-http-and-www-to-non-www