# Forcing HTTPS with Wordpress on AWS

Tags: htaccess, https

It works on our home page.  so if you go to www.domain.com or http:// www.domain.com it will force you to https://.  So that works.
But if you go directly to http:// www.domain.com/about-us it won't force you back to https.  If you go to https:// www.domain.com/about-us it works fine.  But You have to manually put the 's' in.

I'm running the 'Wordpress HTTPS (SSL)' plugin.

In my htaccess I have:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

And in my wp-config I have:

```
define('WP_HOME','https://www.domain.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','https://www.domain.com');

define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);

if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)
       $_SERVER['HTTPS']='on';
```

**EDIT WITH SOLUTION**

I'm not going to mark this as solved since I don't know why this solution worked for me, as the code should actually work the way I have it based on everything I've read from here and from Amazon concerning their ELBs. The important thing to remember that the X-Forwarded-Proto is the key here and is the header passed through the ELB.
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/redirect-http-https-elb/

I ended up moving the RewriteCond & RewriteRule from the .htaccess to my .conf file and everything is working now as expected.

Comment: Use the Recommended `.htaccess` CODE from here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/256042/110572 and remove the `if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false)` CODE from your `wp-config.php`.

Comment: Thanks for the link. My issue is, I need the if statement. Since my AWS load balancer is stripping out the HTTPS and communicating to the back end server via HTTP.  Without the IF it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: Ah, OK, got that. However, in that case, `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']` may not even be set. Check with `isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'] )` in the if condition first.

Comment: @Fayaz sorry, I'm playing catch up here. Using the your recommended code from the link I see you are forwarding from `http://www.ex.com to https://ex.com`. We'd like to keep it at www, but also we have `qa.ex.com` for testing. Right now it strips of the "qa" and redirects to `https://ex.com`. All the https is working on the back end just still not redirecting `http://qa.ex.com/about to https://qa.ex.com/about`

Comment: Since your load balancer is communicating with http, those rules may not work anyway. Best if you can redirect users from the load balancer. In case that's not possible, then you'll have to check what variable your load balancer is forwarding to detect the scenario properly. Here you'll find a similar case with CloudFlare: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20419821/854549

Comment: On another note: it's also possible that your `wp-config.php` is forcing HTTPS, but your `RewriteRule` is not working at all. May be your Apache `mod_rewrite` module is not being loaded at all. Check if your apache configuration has something like this: `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so`. If not then add it & restart apache & see if your original CODE is working.

Comment: I know for sure the mod_rewrite is on and working according to the phpconfig and `if (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'htaccess_tester.php') === false) {echo "working";}` script that I tried.  I've also gone in to my .htaccess and removed the "!" in the condition and I get a redirect loop.  So the changes I'm making seem to be taking effect.  The only page that still redirects is the home page, but I agree I think that's coming from the WP side, not the htaccess. I've even gone in and stripped out everything from the htaccess except the bare minimum with the same results.

Comment: Great, that means `mod_rewrite` is working. Now just check what value you are getting from `mod_rewrite` for different pages. Like, if `RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https` directive is working, or, `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} =off` directive is working. You can test different values by placing different temporary redirects. Once the test is done, use the value that worked.

Comment: Well I need to check to the X-Forwarded-Proto since that's the only thing the ELB passes through.  BUT...  I think I got it.  I moved the configuration from the .htaccess to the conf file.  Seems to have worked.  Not sure why, but I'll take it.

Comment: Check your Apache conf for `AllowOverride All`, if `AllowOverride none` or something else was set, `.htaccess` will not work properly.

Comment: Thought about that. The root of my wordpress site is in /var/www/html I double checked that dir does have AllowOverride All.