# PHP - redirect https to http and www to non-www

Tags: php, functions, redirect, htaccess, wp-redirect

## **EDIT: I finally figured this out. Scroll down for my self-answered self-accepted answer (green check mark) **

I'm currently using `functions.php` to redirect `https` urls to `http` for a site which currently has no SSL certificate:

```
function shapeSpace_check_https() { 
if ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
    
    return true; 
}
    return false;
}


function bhww_ssl_template_redirect() {
if ( shapeSpace_check_https() ) {

    if ( 0 === strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http' ) ) {
    
        wp_redirect( preg_replace( '|^https://|', 'http://', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ), 301 );
        exit();
    } else {
            wp_redirect( 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . 
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 301 );
            exit(); 
        }
    
    }

}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'bhww_ssl_template_redirect');
```

In this same function, I'd like to also redirect the `www` subdomain to non-www. I've found a good function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2079466/6647188), but need help implementing it into my current function. I'd like to avoid doing this in `.htaccess`, but would welcome a solution there as well.

Comment: Redirecting `https` to `http` you need to first have a valid ssl to make the initial handshake and then make the redirect.

Comment: W/ the function above I'm able to successfully redirect `https` to `http`. Downside is the user still has to pass through a scary browser prompt saying there is no valid ssl certificate. I'm fine with that for now - I'm just struggling with redirecting a `www` to non via `preg_replace()`. I need an 'or' operator in there somewhere saying `'https:// | https://www.'`

Comment: You can try this `$url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$redirect_url=''
   $not_allowed = array('https://wwww', 'https://');
   foreach($not_allowed as $types) {
      if(strpos($url, $types) === 0) {
        $redirect_url = str_replace($types, 'http://', $url);
      }
   }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your help. But the following code is what finally worked for me to 301 redirect `https` to `http` and `www` to non-www. I placed the following code block inside of `functions.php`:

```
//check if https being used regardless of certificate
function shapeSpace_check_https() { 
    if ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] !== 'off') || $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) {
        return true; 
    }
    return false;
}


for ($x=0; $x<1; $x++) {
    //if https:// && www.
    if ( shapeSpace_check_https() && substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) === 'www.'){
            header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
            header('Location: http://' . substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 4).$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            exit;
            break;
    //if only www.
    } elseif (substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 0, 4) === 'www.') {
            header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
            header('Location: http://' . substr($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 4).$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            exit;
            break;
    //if only https://
    } elseif ( shapeSpace_check_https() ) {
            header('HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently');
            header('Location: http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
            exit;
            break;
    }
}
```

I don't think I need the `break;`'s, but I definitely need the `exit;`'s and I left the `break;`'s just in case. Please feel free to school me on why I may not need both. The code above results in the following redirects:

https://www.example.com to http://example.com

https://example.com to http://example.com

http://www.example.com to http://example.com

Comment: Thank you. It works.

Answer (score 3):

## How to redirect `HTTPS` to `HTTP` and `www` to `non-www` URL with `.htaccess`:

1. First make sure `HTTPS` is working and valid. It's easy (and free) to do with [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) these days.

   > ***Note:*** Although you are redirecting `HTTPS` to `HTTP`, I'd recommend doing it the opposite, i.e. `HTTP` to `HTTPS`. Better for Security, SEO & Browser compatibility - popular browsers are increasingly making it difficult for `HTTP` sites.
2. Then make sure `.htaccess` and `mod_rewrite` module is working.
3. Then use the following CODE in the `.htaccess` file of your web root directory (if you are already using some rules there, adjust them accordingly with these new rules):

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
       RewriteEngine On

       RewriteCond %{HTTPS}        =on   [OR]
       RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^example\.com$
       RewriteRule ^(.*)$          "http://example.com/$1" [R=301,L]

       # remaining htaccess mod_rewrite CODE for WordPress
   </IfModule>
   ```

   > ***Note:*** Replace `example.com` with your own domain name.

---

### Why `.htaccess` solution is better:

It's better to do these sort of redirects with the web server. From your question, since your web server seems to be `Apache`, it's better to do with `.htaccess`. Why:

1. It's faster.
2. Your `functions.php` file remains cleaner & does what it's originally there for, i.e. Theme modifications.
3. Changing the theme will not affect this.
4. For every redirect, the entire WordPress codebase doesn't have to load twice - once before redirect & then after redirect.

Comment: Thanks for this. I've tried it, but for some reason changes to `.htaccess` won't take effect (I've tried your way and others). Wondering if I need to restart something to force it to work.

Comment: First of all, if you don't install HTTPS (SSL) properly, then `.htaccess` rules for HTTPS may not work at all (I've written this in my answer already). Also, you must make sure `.htaccess` is actually working on your site, because if it does, restarting should not be necessary.

Answer (score 2):

Taken from your code I would refactor it like this:

```
function bhww_ssl_template_redirect() {
    $redirect_url='';
    if ( shapeSpace_check_https() ) {
        if ( 0 === strpos( $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'http' ) ) {
            $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

            $not_allowed = array('https://www', 'https://');
            foreach($not_allowed as $types) {
                if(strpos($url, $types) === 0) {
                    $redirect_url = str_replace($types, 'http://', $url); 
                } 
            }
        } else {
            $redirect_url ='http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        }

            $redirect_url = !empty($redirect_url)?$redirect_url:$url;
            wp_redirect($redirect_url, 301 );
            exit(); 
    }
}
```

Add it the `.htaccess` rules for the redirect www-> non - www

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://yourdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Redirecting https->http

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But again for this to work you need to have a valid SSL or the "Terror screen" will be shown to users.

Comment: Thanks so much for taking the time to do this. Unfortunately the `www` is not getting removed from the address bar in my case - I don't think it's redirecting. I did remove the extra 'w' typo from 'https://wwww' in your code, and also tried a version w/ `if(strpos($url, $types) !==0)` instead of your `===0` because I thought that may be the problem, but couldn't get it to work. I'll keep staring at it to see what I can change. If you have any ideas pls let me know.

Comment: This is maybe due to the system .htaccess settings. I would try it in private window and look for hidden redirects.

Comment: Thx for coming back to this. I've tried doing this in `.htaccess` w/ yours and other methods, but can't get it to take effect - I think I may need to de-activate and re-activate my wordpress theme to get `.htaccess` changes to take effect, but I'm not ready to take that step (never done it). So I'll stick w/ PHP - still can't get it to work. Your way successfully redirects to https to http, but I still can't get it to remove the www subdomain.
I checked in a private window and didn't see any hidden redirects in the `Network` tab (if thats how u check) - just the expected https -> http 301.

Comment: I did notice after your `if else` statement you had the `if` shorthand: `$redirect_url = !empty($redirect_url)?$redirect_url:$url;` , but `$url` isn't defined globally here - its only defined in the `if` statement. Not sure if that's a reason or not - maybe `$url` is globally defined in PHP, or isn't needed anyways?

Comment: @KyleVassella 1) The $url isn't something should be declared globally as it serves only the local scope for the if statement. It holds the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and should be taken in to account if the `$redirect_url` stay empty.  2) The .htaccess should work as is without the activation/deactivation of themes. But there is a big if this could change if there is a caching or something else interfering with the rules. I would try to push the rules at the top of the `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

Here, use this updated function to redirect a www site to non-www:

```
function bhww_ssl_template_redirect() {
    $redirect_url='';
    $url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    if ( shapeSpace_check_https() ) {
        if ( 0 === strpos( $url, 'http' ) ) {
            if(strpos($url, 'https://') === 0) {
                $redirect_url = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $url); 
            } 
        } 
        elseif ( TRUE == strpos( $url, 'www.') {
             $redirect_url = str_replace('www.', '', $url); 
        } 
        else {
            $redirect_url ='http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] .  $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        }
            $redirect_url = !empty($redirect_url)?$redirect_url:$url;
            wp_redirect($redirect_url, 301 );
            exit(); 
    }
}
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this. I didn't try it before I got my own version to work. I would have, but at the time couldn't risk possibly breaking the live site again. Your way may work, though off the top of my head I don't think it would redirect `http://www.example.com` to `http://example.com` since all the logic is inside of `if (shapeSpace_check_https() )` , which I believe checks if `https` is being used. I could be wrong though.