# Redirect www to non-www htaccess

Tags: redirect, htaccess, https, http

It's been asked a gazillion times but it's still not working in my Wordpress. I want to redirect everything to https://website.com.
Current code been used:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

based on [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54070927/apache-2-htaccess-wont-redirect-www-non-www) but I also tried [all in this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/234723/generic-htaccess-redirect-www-to-non-www/235064#235064) and of course [this other one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/256038/htaccess-https-redirect-from-www-to-non-www). Maybe I am missing something but this is what happens no matter what combination I tried:

```
# http://website.com      -> https://website.com
# https://website.com     -> https://website.com
# http://www.website.com  -> https://www.website.com     #wrong#
# https://www.website.com  -> https://www.website.com     #wrong#
```

I am starting to wonder whether the let's encrypt installation has something to do... or even some other modification done in wp-config.php... I added this in the past:

```
if ( defined( 'WP_CLI' ) ) {
    $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = 'localhost';
}

define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
define('WP_HOME', 'https://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/');
```

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Where exactly have you put the redirect directives in the `.htaccess` file in relation to the WordPress front-controller?

Comment: Hi, it's in the first lines of the htaccess, before anything else.

Comment: Are you using WP "pretty" permalinks? For for 4 examples... should that last one be _from_ HTTPS, not HTTP as stated (otherwise it's just the same as the previous example)?

Comment: Apologies, I edited it now. My mistake. I answered you also below. And I am not using any plugin for standard permalinks (there is a section of the wp fully controlled by a plugin but it shouldn't affect as some pages are independent e.g. the main page, and redirects fail there too)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} website\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [R,L]
```

@elgoots, the reason yours was close but still had trouble is your HTTP_HOST has the www in it.

Comment: sigh. you are right. derp. this is why i shouldnt answer questions at 4am lol

Comment: You just made me a happy man. Thanks! I can't remember how many different combinations I tried! Thanks also to you Elgoots :)

Comment: @elgoots, yep me too, I try to only answer questions in the morning AFTER I've had a cup of coffee!

Comment: But this is "only" an HTTP to HTTPS redirect. This will fail to canonicalise the www subdomain in a request for `https://www.website.com` (as stated in the question) - leaving it up to WordPress itself to canonicalise the request later (which it may well be doing). The first condition is superfluous - as it will always be successful (assuming we are dealing with just a single domain).

Comment: "your HTTP_HOST has the www in it" - I assume you are referring to the first code block in @Elgoots answer? Yes, true, but WordPress itself should have then canonicalised the www subdomain. And this does not apply to the 2nd code block, given the order of the two rules (since the www subdomain would already have been removed by the time the second rule was processed).

Comment: This takes any request for either the www. version or non-www. version as well as http (vs https) requests and sends them ALL to the httpS non-www version.  It captures all with the fewest lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

Setting the wordpress home and site url manually to https://website.com

Then remove all other rules in .htaccess and have:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

The htaccess will redirect to https for all traffic and all pages/posts/categories etc.

As for dropping the www infront, the site url and homepage url should take care of that in the wordpress framework.

Give it a try and report back.

If that does not work, try the following and manually set the request uri. Obviously change website.com with your domain:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.website.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: Hi, I removed the lines from the wp-config and this is what happened:   ```# http://website.com      -> https://website.com
# https://website.com     -> https://website.com
# http://www.website.com  -> https://website.com     #this one changed, now OK#
# https://www.website.com  -> https://www.website.com     #wrong#  ```    what is exactly request uri?

Comment: @AdrianInfante Was that without changing your existing `.htaccess` directives?

Comment: @MrWhite, following Elgoots comments, the first thing I did was to remove the code from the wp-config and do the home and site set manually.  From that point on, the only redirection working wrong was https://www to https://.  I changed afterwards htaccess as recommended but it didn't do any other change. At the moment I am with 3 redirections OK, 1 wrong.

Comment: So are you saying now using my suggestion: 

`https://www.website.com redirects to https://www.website.com`

So the issue is that it did not remove the www. infront ?

Comment: @Elgoots exactly!

Comment: @Adrian Assuming you tried the 2nd code block then that should have worked OK (providing you cleared your browser cache etc.)? `https://www.website.com` would have been redirected to `https://website.com/` by the first rule in the 2nd code block - the same rule that redirected `http://www` to `https://`. (The first code block is simply a HTTP to HTTPS redirect, maintaining the same hostname - which would be a requirement should you ever decide to implement HSTS.)

Comment: @MrWhite I was trying all the time in Incognito mode, cleaning completely the browser and Ctrl+F5 (just in case) each time. Not sure why, but only the solution from Trisha worked for me. I have some extra code in the wp-config.php file, maybe it didn't work with your code because of that. No idea!